# Website displaying graphs (google charts) with live data from mysql server using php keeps crashing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli, graph

I have been creating a website that displays live data from a TI sensor tag in a table. The data is sent to a mysql server, from which it is fetched using a php script and put into a json file (which all works well).

I am then using a html file with javascript to call upon the json data and transfer it into several graphs, which once again all works and the graphs are displayed and live updating. However, the website will then crash after roughly 2 minutes of running. Google chrome displays a link to [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?p=e_awsnap&rd=1)

The mysql server is host on a raspberry Pi 2. [This](http://143.167.158.41/charts1.html) is the link to the website that will crash after 2 minutes or so:

The piece of javascript that creates one of the charts (they are all very similar) and then refreshes the data is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function drawChart() {
     var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "php/connection3_temp.php",
          dataType:"json",
          }).done(function (results) {

          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

          data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Ambient Temp.');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Object Temp.');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Humidity');

          $.each(results, function (i, row) {
            data.addRow([
              (new Date(row.timestamp)),
              parseFloat(row.amb_temp),
              parseFloat(row.obj_temp),
              parseFloat(row.hum)
            ]);
          });

         var options = {
          title: 'Temperature and Humidity against Time',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' },
          series: {
                0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
                1: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
                2: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
          },
          vAxes: {0:    {title: 'Temp. (°C)',
                        minValue: 0,
                        maxValue: 30
                        },
                  1:    {title: 'Humidity (%)',
                        minValue: 20,
                        maxValue: 80
                        }
                 },
          hAxis: {
                  title: 'Time (s)'
                 },
        };

          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#temp_chart').get(0)); 
          chart.draw(data, options);

        });

      }
    setInterval(function(){drawChart()}, 2000);

      // load chart lib
      google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['corechart']
      });

      // call drawChart once google charts is loaded
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

</script>
```

The php code is:

```
    <?php



$servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "raspberryblue";
    $dbname = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sensortag3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3000";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    // All good?
    if ( !$result ) {
      // Nope
      $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error() . "<br>";
      $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $sql;
      die( $message );
    }

    // Print out rows
    $prefix = '';
    echo "[\n";
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
      echo $prefix . " {\n";
      echo '  "timestamp": "' . $row['timestamp'] . '",' . "\n";
      echo '  "amb_temp": "' . $row['amb_temp'] . '",' . "\n";
      echo '  "obj_temp": "' . $row['obj_temp'] . '",' . "\n";
      echo '  "hum": "' . $row['hum'] . '"' . "\n"; 
      echo " }";
      $prefix = ",\n";
    }
    echo "\n]";

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: `php/connection3_temp.php` cant tell without that code

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. Will add it in. I think the issue might be with the way it is redrawing the whole chart using "setInterval(function(){drawChart()}, 2000);", maybe there is a way to just refresh the data instead?

Comment: Please add it to the question. And that website seems to be already `crashed`

Comment: I've added it. Strange, I can still open it on google chrome